# What is the meaning of "migration" in "Oracle (database) migration"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

Does the term *migration* typically imply *to* or *from*?

For instance, if I refer to a specific database migration project, where the database is Oracle, would "Oracle migration" refer to:

1. migrating from another database to Oracle
2. migrating from Oracle to another database
3. migrating from one version of Oracle to a different version of Oracle

Comment: It's ambiguous, but I'd first interpret it to mean the migration between versions of Oracle.

Comment: It means none of these things. In and of itself it means the migration *of* oracles. Not to oracles, not from oracles, but of oracles. People who predict the future, moving from one place to another. For it to get to mean anything to do with computers, you'll need a whole bunch of context already. And while you're doing that anyway, you might as well go the whole nine yards and clarify all the other things that can use clarification.

Comment: If it's the title of a book, the book has something to do with Oracle (or an oracle) and some kind of migration. That's what the title means to me. If I wanted a more precise idea what the book is about, I'd look for a description elsewhere, perhaps on the back cover.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Context matters. It might most commonly mean a migration of oracles, but it doesn't inherently mean that.

Comment: @HotLicks I wouldn't. Migration generally suggests a change that's not just upgrading to a later version. Using "migration" would make sense if the two versions are fundamentally different, though, because at that point changing from ProductX version 1 to ProductX version 2 is likely no different (in terms of workload) to changing from ProductX version 1 to ProductY. As a general rule, if the newer version is backwards compatible with the older version, "migration" wouldn't be the correct word.

Comment: Just to add to the ambiguity, a business article entitled "Oracle Migration" _could_ refer to an exodus of Oracle Corporation employees to find other employment.

Comment: The same way we resolve all ambiguity. **Context**! (rainbow emoji)

Comment: I want to add one more, It could also mean a Migration of Data conducted by the Local Oracle Team, which can be disastrous. If you have lived one of those, god's know there's only one way to call it "Oracle Migration".

Comment: This is a better question for a programming board, but not a stackexchange one. There you're almost certainly going to hear that the majority of times it's used to refer to migrating *to* a platform, but there will be votes on all sides. It's domain specific. It has nothing to do with general English usage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a domain specific question, not a general EL&U question.

Comment: In the Stack Exchange bubble it's easy to forget that computer programmers are less than one percent of the native-English-speaking workforce, and an even smaller percentage of the population as a whole. So if you're looking for a generally applicable answer, the SE Hot Network Questions crowd is not a good sample. On the other hand, if you *know* that your title will only be seen by a tech audience, you should edit the specifics into your question so answers can take that into account.

Comment: @RegDwigнt It doesn't even mean "migration of oracles," as it's unknown whether "Oracle" is a proper noun or not without context.

Comment: Pythia had to get to [Delphi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi) somehow

Comment: @1006a *In the Stack Exchange bubble it's easy to forget that computer programmers are less than one percent of the native-English-speaking workforce* English speaking workforce is a pretty vast criterion, so where did you get that figure? I mean, I really want to believe that stat but I'm not sure if it's true for the US. And the majority of users are American, and maybe followed by Brits and Indians.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I admit I was extrapolating from US statistics. Per the US Bureau of Labor Statistics, the [civilian workforce in 2016 was ~160 million](https://data.bls.gov/timeseries/LNS11000000); of these, a little [under 300,000 were classed as computer programmers](https://www.bls.gov/ooh/computer-and-information-technology/computer-programmers.htm). That works out to just under two tenths of a percent of the labor force. My assumption was that the ratio would not have been different enough in the rest of the anglosphere to move the total share above a full one percent.

Comment: When google is actually ***useful***. See "Oracle Database migration" at this address!: https://docs.oracle.com/en/solutions/migrate-database-between-oracle-cloud-infrastructure-shapes/plan-oracle-database-migration1.html#GUID-E5CCC459-299D-4A3F-AF0C-C956317D78AA

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is ambiguous...

On the one hand, it may be about migrating data to Oracle. On the other hand, it may be about migrating data from Oracle. It can also be about migrating to and from Oracle. And which meaning is the most correct depends on the context. If we only have 2 words, Oracle Migration, I really don't know which thing is meant.

By the way, before posting my answer, I asked a very good software engineer about what he thinks about it, and he said the same thing - it's ambiguous.

So, context is everything.

Comment: When I read "Oracle Migration" my first thought was some type of bird and how they migrate. As an edit, I guess I am not the only one as this is an answer.

Comment: Wait was he an engineer of very good software or a software engineer that was very good?

Comment: @mowwwalker he is a software engineer that is very good.

Comment: He's a software engineer that's very good, but he's a terrible software engineer. :-)

Comment: All joking aside, as a software engineer, I agree that it's ambiguous, but the "migration to Oracle" interpretation is more likely than "migration from Oracle." However it could also mean migrating Oracle databases from one server to another, or from one Oracle version to another.

Comment: Oracle migration could also be the process by which a prediction is modified over time to more closely approximate the likely outcome.

Comment: As a very good engineer of terrible software, I agree with @LarsH

Comment: As a very good Software Engineer (tm), There actually is a historical context that heavily implies it means "migrate away from". Of course, the most immediate context would override that context. I explained the historical context in an answer.

Comment: I think most people (the ones that know Oracle as a database) will interpret it as "migration to Oracle" because when you see a product name in the tile you usually want people either use that product or to switch to it.

Comment: @ChatterOne Unless everyone in the industry is abandoning that product like rats on a sinking ship. (That's not true anymore, but it used to be so true I'm surprised it survived)

Comment: @Tezra you might have a point, because after 11 years spent on coding Perl, if I saw a "Perl Migration" book, I'd immediately think "Run! Ruuuuuuun!"

Comment: Migrate data in Oracle Database Cloud Service between Oracle Cloud Infrastructure shapes at: https://docs.oracle.com/en/solutions/migrate-database-between-oracle-cloud-infrastructure-shapes/plan-oracle-database-migration1.html#GUID-E5CCC459-299D-4A3F-AF0C-C956317D78AA

Answer (score 25):

A fourth interpretation might be that Oracle itself is migrating

> Bird migration takes place seasonally

Comment: True, I thought it was about traveling fortune tellers.

Comment: SELECT Coconut FROM Mercia WHERE IsMigratory(Coconut);

Comment: @RobertColumbia ORA-06500: PL/SQL: storage error

Comment: This is what I had in mind, about a bird I have never heard of.

Answer (score 16):

If I saw "Oracle Migration" as the subject of an email about an upcoming meeting, I would probably assume that it was about migrating **TO** Oracle.  However, it is definitely not 100% clear without any other context.

Source- I am a native speaker and a software engineer.

Comment: +1 - But, if your employer uses Oracle already, the subject reads as migration FROM Oracle. Source: I'm a software engineer and we're currently migrating from Oracle to MongoDB. =)

Comment: To add to the confusion even more, it could be about migrating Oracle databases from one platform to another.  Source: Also a software engineer and working on migrating customers from HP3000s to Linux servers.

Comment: My assumption would be based largely on whether or not we already used Oracle... If we didn't I'd assume it was TO. If we did, I'd assume it was either to a)a different version b)a different platform c)a different type of db. If I worked in a different field I might assume it was migration of actual Oracles (or you had misspelled Orioles)

Comment: I agree with @OnoSendai - it's ambiguous without context. I could easily and equally interpret it as migration either to *or* from Oracle.

Comment: I am also a software engineer. This activity would describe (for example) migrating from SQL Server *TO* Oracle. Going from one version of Oracle to another would be "upgrading" Oracle. Moving Oracle from one server to another would be a "server migration". So its a little ambiguous but I think "migrate to Oracle" is most likely.

Answer (score 10):

It is ambiguous.

Without more context it is not clear what "Oracle" refers to.

As per the [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/oracle), "**oracle**" is defined as:

> A priest or priestess acting as a medium through whom advice or prophecy was sought from the gods in classical antiquity.

However, there is also "**Oracle Corporation**" which [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation) describes as:

> [A]n American multinational computer technology corporation headquartered in Redwood Shores, California. The company specializes primarily in developing and marketing database software and technology, cloud engineered systems, and enterprise software products — particularly its own brands of database management systems.

As other answers have expounded upon, it might be reasonable to conclude that "Migration" refers to a [data migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_migration) or [scheme migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) specific to an Oracle (Corporation) Database. However, without any context confirming that "Oracle" is referring to a computer database, that meaning is not clear.

Consider this [definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/migration) of **migration**:

> Movement of people to a new area or country in order to find work or better living conditions.

For many non-technical individuals (or individuals who do not recall that a company named Oracle exists), they may only understand "Oracle" by the dictionary definition. In that case, the title suggests that one or more priests are relocating.

Answer (score 8):

It could also mean a migration within an Oracle database. In that case it would mean migrating from one version of an application database to the next (rather than updating the underlying database management system itself).

Comment: This was my first thought, as that's the situation that most recently applied to my team.

Answer (score 8):

As a software engineer, allow me to explain why Software Engineers assume people know what "Oracle Migration" means, using a very brief simplified history.

In the early days of computers, Oracle was the **the** Enterprise (top of the line) Database. You were either using Oracle as your database, or you didn't have a database. (Also, computers were expensive, and programmers were cheap labor.)

Over time, computers got cheaper, programmers became more valuable, and competition for Oracle started to appear. Oracle was getting old, massive, and ludicrously expensive. So a sort of mass migration from Oracle to **any other database** started to happen, as competing databases could offer more business value for cheaper.

Because **everyone** was trying to migrate away from Oracle before it died completely, it become "common knowledge" that Oracle migration meant migrating away from Oracle. You were either required to use Oracle by contract, or you migrated to something better.

However, to everyone's surprise, the Oracle database survived! And they are still updating! And it isn't *completely* trash any more. It's still (arguably) ludicrously expensive, but it is at least viable for the foreseeable future (it's currently the #1 Relational Database by stock value, thanks to ludicrously expensive support contracts!). So now that there is no longer a mass exodus from Oracle databases, the "common knowledge" is no longer common, and it is now ambiguous. The old guard will still stand by that Oracle should be ditched in a heartbeat, but the new bloods are used to just working with whatever is handed to them.

#### Additional Note:

Also, context makes all the difference in the world. If you aren't using Oracle, it probably means migrating *to*; if you are upgrading servers, it means migrating versions, if you do use Oracle, it probably means migrating *from*.

If it's a blog title, it probably means "from Oracle" because if you are migrating databases, Oracle is still the most common legacy (used since COBOL software days) database in use.

Comment: And if you're anywhere but Stack Exchange, it has nothing whatsoever to do with computers, and refers to people who can see the future upping sticks.

Comment: The question is not why some people assume they know what "Oracle Migration" means. The question is whether it is ambiguous. And your answer shows clearly that it is - as do all the other answers, if not by their content then by their very existence.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You misunderstand the answer. I'm explaining why there was a time this was considered unambiguous, and why it is ambiguous now; which is **exactly** what the OP is trying to understand.

Comment: Does "no. 1 by stock value" have any meaning?  AFAIK the free-software databases have approximately zero stock value, but a heck of a lot of *community value*...

Comment: @TobySpeight it just means that of all the databases, it makes the most money. Which implies that it still enjoys a significant amount of use, and that it's unlikely they are going to shutdown the project anytime soon.

Comment: But the converse is far from true - PostgreSQL or MariaDB aren't going to disappear just because they are not in the same game of "making money".  OTOH, "significantly used" is a much more relevant metric.  (I'm happy to end this off-topic discussion now, if you are!)

Comment: @TobySpeight The logic in the answer is A:It makes lots of money -> B:Oracle isn't going to abandon something that makes lots of money -> C:You can use Oracle DB without fear of support/security patches stopping anytime soon. This logic makes no argument about the viability of other dbs in any way. So in short "Because Oracle DB makes lots of money, Oracle DB is a viable product". That does not imply it is good, practical, affordable, or the best. It only implies that it works for real-world applications. So the #1 by stock, is just to support the claim it is still viable (indirectly).

Answer (score 7):

As a native English speaker, I read this as

> The migration of an oracle.

I imagined a horse-drawn carriage with an elderly person dressed in flowing tattered clothes and an old knotted branch as a walking cane. Having been kicked out of their previous town for making too many false predictions, this oracle began a migration to find a more receptive audience.

Comment: I never knew you could use the term for a single person. Is that really true?

Comment: @Gnudiff Sure. From [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/migrate): _He migrates from New York to Florida each winter._

Comment: Though I suppose you could also imagine a troupe of oracles.

Answer (score 5):

As a native English speaker (although I suspect that's not relevant), I would immediately recognize this as a shorthand expression for something that is well defined elsewhere. (Unless everyone involved happen to be ornithologists, in which case, it probably is a literal expression.) It could mean any of those things you think it means, but it certainly only refers to one specific thing.

It's certainly easier among those who know the meaning to talk it about it in shorthand rather than refer to it with a fuller descriptive label.

As with any coined terminology, anyone who doesn't know its meaning can ask someone who does. From that point, they will probably begin using the shorthand themselves, if they need to refer to it at all.

It only become ambiguous when someone starts using shorthand to mean something different than is commonly meant (and by "commonly", I don't mean as it is literally meant). In cases like this, it's important to make sure everyone involved is on board with what the intended meaning is among the group who are communicating. I see this all of the time, especially when someone wants to usurp a universally defined term.

For example, in my business we talk about the *Spurious Free Dynamic Range*. This has a very precise meaning that is only superficially like its literal meaning. Usually, we can talk among ourselves about it without having to resort to the precise definition. Sometimes, someone wants to talk about something that more closely resembles the literal meaning. How do they refer to it in shorthand without clashing with the universally understood meaning (within this discipline) and without being overly wordy every time it comes up? That can be a problem.

In your case, unless there are people dealing with more than one activity that might be referred to as the "Oracle migration", then its not ambiguous. Otherwise, expect that someone is going to be confused and misinformed at some point in time.

Answer (score 3):

I've worked at different companies where this term has been used in very different ways.  It depends on what's happening within the environment.  IT management loves their quick PowerPoint slide titles, and being thoughtful or precise isn't a strong point in that world.  In my experience, when IT management uses an especially broad or ambiguous term, like "Oracle Migration," there's a semi-conscious implication that this is a high priority for management, and therefore for you too.  Or it's just sloppy writing -- YMMV.

A database migration is always a huge project, so it could be any of these:

- In an environment where a legacy database of non-Oracle origin will
  be migrated to an Oracle instance, the **to** is implicit. 
  Announcements might be accompanied by fanfare about how we've grown
  so much as a company that we're using Oracle now.
- Where there's a project to move data from, let's say, a very old
  Oracle database where an in-place upgrade isn't possible, this means
  Oracle at both ends.  This is probably more likely to be said when
  there are other database vendors in the house.
- A migration from an Oracle database to a non-Oracle database
  (PostgreSQL, Mongo, you name it).  Probably accompanied by fanfare
  about how much money will be saved in the licensing budget.

Answer (score -5):

This is only ambiguous to people who don't know anything about Larry Ellison's company Oracle, don't speak English very well, or who want to argue for the sake of arguing.

It is entirely clear to native speakers who are also involved in computing. No professional in the industry would ever assume that "Oracle Migration" meant anything but

> The Process of Migrating To (or from, it makes no difference) Using Oracle Instead of Another Database Provider

which may include, but would not be limited to, existing database engines, software products, support contracts, etc.

Comment: I'd have to disagree.  My company migrates data from and to Oracle so "Oracle Migration" could refer to either.

Comment: As a native English speaker, with access to Oracle databases, I'd disagree. It could still be Migrating from Oracle instead of to.  There is no direction implied by the word migration.

Comment: +1 This now explains the oddly high number of views. It's to do with computer stuff.  I thought the OP had made the expression up.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: And the end result is, it's bikeshedding of the first order.

Comment: I too disagree.  Having been in the biz for nearly 40 years, yes, I thought of Oracle the company first, but then wondered about birds (as I know there are many species I know nothing about.)  But even in the context of the database, it could be about moving _to_ Oracle, moving _from_ Oracle, moving _from_ one version of Oracle _to_ another, or moving Oracle from one platform to another.  It absolutely _is_ ambiguous, even in the context of computing.

Comment: It is entirely clear to me that a chapter in MySQL manual titled  "Oracle Migration" would deal with migration **from** Oracle. Don't be so quick to judge.

Comment: The difference is not the preposition, which hardly matters. Ultimately, who cares? It's about Oracle, not "an oracle."

Comment: I am a native English speaker, a software engineer familiar with Oracle, and not particularly argumentative, and lacking context I would find this phrase ambiguous. Your explanation is *likely*, but there are multiple other possible meanings that are not significantly less likely.

Comment: The question does **not** ask what this phrase means 'to native speakers who are also involved in computing'. It asks what the phrase means to native speakers.

Comment: The question specifically suggests that "*to*" or "*from*" **is** important in its (unspecified) context.  If you just skip over that distinction, you're not answering the question that's asked.

Comment: The fact that more than one person (many of whom work in the field of computers) claim it's ambiguous suggests it is in fact ambiguous. If conversely everyone was claiming it was clear cut with just one or two exceptions, then maybe it wouldn't be clear cut...

Comment: @asylum I don't care. The point is, this question is not germane to English, and has been closed as such. Find your entertainment elsewhere.